# How to fix the index in my pandas dataframe to not keeping the value only to zero, and to have an increasing value?

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, dataframe

Currently, I'm working on a comparison of key points of two images in a Python script. If I run the cv2 comparison script, the results of the comparison are stored in a Pandas dataframe. In this dataframe, the index is keeping the value to zero(0) and not increasing after each run of the script.

Please see below the result:

```
Key_points_1        Key_points_2        Percentage      Result
0   2737    2709    0.84    Fail
0   2737    2709    0.84    Fail
0   2737    3283    25.16   Pass
0   2737    3283    25.16   Pass
```

```py
# Create pandas dataframe with the data from comparison.

    initial_data = {'Key_points_1': [int(len(kp_1))],
                    'Key_points_2': [int(len(kp_2))],
                    'Percentage': [percentage]}

    df = pd.DataFrame(initial_data, columns=['Key_points_1', 'Key_points_2', 'Percentage'])

    result = []
    for value in df["Percentage"]:
        if value >= 15:
            result.append("Pass")   # Threshold to be defined.
        else:
            result.append("Fail")   # Threshold to be defined.

    df["Result"] = result

    df.to_csv('output/cvs_DataFrame.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', mode='a', header=False)
```

The desired result should be as follows:

```
Index   Key_points_1        Key_points_2        Percentage      Result
0        2737                 2709                0.84           Fail
1        2737                 2709                0.84           Fail
2        2737                 3283                25.16          Pass
3        2737                 3283                25.16          Pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Better is use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead your loop solution:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df["Result"] = np.where(df["Percentage"] >= 15,"Pass", "Fail")
print (df)
   Key_points_1  Key_points_2  Percentage Result
0          2737          2709        0.84   Fail
1          2737          2709        0.84   Fail
2          2737          3283       25.16   Pass
3          2737          3283       25.16   Pass
```

Comment: @AlexandruIoan - So there are `0` in index ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I have the same result as before. ```df = df.reset_index(drop=True)``` is not solving the issue. The challenge is that I don't have the key points 1 and 2, the percentage and the result predefine, but for each execution of the script, there will be added a new row in the data frame.

Comment: yes, there is still index 0 for each row after I execute the script with new input images

Comment: @AlexandruIoan - One idea - Is possible use `df.to_csv('output/cvs_DataFrame.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', mode='a', header=False, index=False)` ?

Comment: I've tried to make ```index=False``` but the issue now is that I don't have the index, and I need somehow a reference to the last row (last script comparison) to check if the result was "pass" or "fail".

Comment: Maybe there is another way to refer to the last row in order to check if the result was 'pass' or 'fail'. I was thinking to have the index to use ```.iloc[]``` in order to get the last row information, but maybe do you think is possible to create another column which extends its number to the length of the data frame? And then from there to check the result of the last number?